# How to generate app bundles for publishing a Compose Multiplatform app for Android, iOS, Web, and Desktop?

Tags: bundle, publish

I'm currently working on a Compose Multiplatform project using Kotlin, and I'm looking for guidance on how to generate app bundles for publishing my app on various platforms, including Android, iOS, Web, and Desktop.

My project is set up to target multiple platforms, and I've successfully built and tested the app for each platform individually. However, I'm unsure about the specific steps and tools required to generate app bundles or distribution packages for each platform.

Specifically, I'm interested in learning:

- How to generate an Android App Bundle (AAB) for publishing on the Google Play Store.
- How to generate an iOS App Bundle (IPA) for distribution on the Apple App Store.
- How to package the app for deployment on the web using Kotlin/WASM and Compose for Web.
- How to create executable files or packages for distributing the app on desktop platforms such as Windows, macOS, and Linux.

If anyone has experience or knowledge about generating app bundles or distribution packages for Compose Multiplatform projects targeting these platforms, I would greatly appreciate any insights, recommendations, or step-by-step guides.

Thank you in advance for your help!